# Git flow diagram release versions and hotfixes

Tags: git, git-flow, hotfix

I am working with git flow on a project and I was looking at the diagram here:

https://datasift.github.io/gitflow/IntroducingGitFlow.html

It makes sense right up to the last image which details the hotfixes.

Could someone tell me why master is on 1.0 (is this a future release number) and yet further down the timeline a hot fix is taken and master is tagged at 1.0.1 and then even further down the release branch start is at 1.0, as if the 1.0.1 is ignored.

To confuse it even more for me at the release cut point it says "from this point on 'next release' means the release after 1.1.0", I take this to mean 1.2.0.

So what actually happened to the 1.1.0 release, to me it looks like it has disapeared.

Can someone help me understand this last diagram please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO the diagram you are looking is wrong.

You should refer at the original diagram : http://nvie.com/files/Git-branching-model.pdf (that was created by Vincent Driessen, who was the first to explain the git-flow model.

You can refer Vincent's article introducing the git-flow model : http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Comment: The diagram you linked makes perfect sense, it does look like the one I was using was incorrect. Thank you for the references.